# How to disable Woocommerce Wordpress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, lms

I am trying to build an application where I interact with external API. Woocommerce is blocking all the basic authenticating I'm making. The problem is I need woocommerce in the wordpress section. How do I fix this issue?

If I deactivate woocommerce, everything works well, once I activate it back, it stops

Comment: I have fixed it. I have to change the authorization key and that works out fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code block.
Open your current active theme's function.php file and go to the end of it. Add below  mentioned code.

// Disable WooCommerce REST API
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_enabled', '__return_false');

Comment: I added it, I got this   {
    "code": "invalid_username",
    "message": "<strong>Error:</strong> Unknown username. Check again or try your email address.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}

Comment: It gave authorisation error. probably my code not work for this.

Comment: Another problem is I cannot make a post request, but I can make get

Comment: Okay. Now I got it. It completely shuts off not only woocommerce but also WP.

Comment: Okay. Now I got it. It completely shuts off not only woocommerce but also WP.